Ensure Access to Vector Table for Both Bootloader and Application
I have a custom board that I am implementing a bootloader and application for based on an Infineon PSoC4 MAX device (Cortex M0 core). The bootloader is located in FLASH starting at address 0x00, while the application is located starting at 0x5000. I have modified the linker scripts for both my bootloader and application to reflect this. However, after doing so, I am not able to debug using the MiniProg4 in the Eclipse IDE. I noticed for the application, my startup file has an error in the Reset_Handler (though the project still builds). I suspect this is why I can't debug. Note the bootloader uses the same startup file, but does NOT flag this as an error.
The error is here:

It seems like an issue with the vector table. I haven't done anything explicit with the vector table for the application; do I need to place it explicitly in the linker script for the application? I know by convention the vector table will be placed at 0x00 in FLASH; by restricting the application loacation to an address of 0x5000 or above is it unable to see the vector table?
Application linker script exerpt:
MEMORY
{
    FLASH_Bootloader (rx)  : ORIGIN = __FLASH_START, LENGTH = 0x00005000
    FLASH_Application (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00005000, LENGTH = __FLASH_SIZE - 0x00005000
    RAM   (rwx) : ORIGIN = __RAM_START,   LENGTH = __RAM_SIZE
  flash_boot_meta   (rw)  : ORIGIN = 0x0005FA00, LENGTH = 0x100
}


Are you expecting that the application uses the bootloader's vector table at 0x00000000?  I think the application should have its own vector table at 0x00005000 and the application should set SCB->VTOR = 0x00005000 during startup.

The Cortex M0 have the vector table fixed at address 0x00000000. You don't need to place in explicity in for the Application. It shall see the vector table, whenever you palce the start_address of Application.

Ussualy you remap the vector table at RAM by using SCB->VTOR. For the CM0 you don't have the VTOR registers. I think yo uhave an issue at line #229/ Are you albe to compile? Does your device is Cortex M0?
